# Alignment of formular after linebreak in amsmath (flalign)

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

in `amsmath`. The best I could come up with so far is the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
    \text{This is the first part } & \\ \text{of a longer text } & = \text{ } \dfrac{\text{One rather long Thing}}{\text{Other Thing}} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

This however does produce only the following:

[image]

I am using `flalign` for a reason not shown in the MWE. The line break has to be there because otherwise the formula would not fit on one line.

Comment: Avoid using `flalign`, in particular for single equations; for multiline displays, use `align`, unless `flalign` is really needed (which is rare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `stackengine` (by our fellow user [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes)) version of  *linebreaking*

There are some macros, but for this purpose, `\Centerstack` seems to be quite useful. The optional argument contains the alignment character, `r` is used for `right justified` stacking. There is a `\Vectorstack` command for math content too. 
The vertical spacing between the stacked items can be set with the `\setstackgap{L}{gap height}` command.

Please change the gap value to the actual needs. I've given a reasonable and a completely exaggerated example ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}


\begin{flalign*}
\setstackgap{L}{10pt}
 \Centerstack[r]{{\text{This is the first part}} {\text{of a longer text}}} & = \text{ } \dfrac{\text{One rather long Thing}}{\text{Other Thing}} &
\end{flalign*}

Exaggerated gap
\begin{flalign*}
\setstackgap{L}{50pt}
 \Vectorstack[r]{{\text{This is the first part}} {\text{of a longer text}}} & = \text{ } \dfrac{\text{One rather long Thing}}{\text{Other Thing}} &
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is an easy way to adjust the spacing between "This is the first part" and "of a longer text"?

Comment: @Thomas: See the update please

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose it in a `\parbox`.

[image: figure 1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
    \text{\parbox{3cm}{This is the first part of a longer text}} = \dfrac{\text{One rather long Thing}}{\text{Other Thing}} \\
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: although it's somewhat implied that the text should be flush left on the page, it's not explicitly required.  if flush left *isn't* required, this could as well be put between `\[ ... \]` as an unnumbered equation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
This is the first part\\
of a longer text
\end{tabular} =
\dfrac{\text{One rather long Thing}}{\text{Other Thing}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]